# Groovy Closure Execution Oddity

Tags: groovy, closures

I have a class that essentially consumes JMS messages, and then proceeds to call a closure with those messages.  The message listener is running in a separate thread.

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import javax.jms.*

@Slf4j
class JMSProducer {

    Connection connection
    List<Queue> queues
    private Session session
    private List<MessageConsumer> messageConsumers

    @Override
    void init() {
        connection.start()
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
        messageConsumers = queues.collect { session.createConsumer(it) }
    }

    @Override
    void produce(final Closure closure) {

        def listener = new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            void onMessage(Message message) {
                if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                    try {
                        log.info("Calling");
                        closure.call(message.object);
                        log.info("Called");
                    } catch(e) {
                        log.error("Error")
                    } finally {
                        log.info("Finally");
                    }
                } else {
                    log.error("Unrecognized message")
                }
            }
        }
        messageConsumers.each {
            it.messageListener = listener
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have with the above code is that I see "Calling", "Called" and "Finally" for all the messages I put into the queue, but the closure itself is only called a fraction of that.

```
//Assume 5 messages have been put into queue, and 
// JMSProducer has been configured to read from queue*

new JMSProducer().produce { message ->
    log.info("Received Message");        
}
```

The "Received Message" is only logging twice (even though I see "Calling"/"Called"/"Finally" five times each).

It's almost as if the closure is being ignored or skipped over.

When I run this inside of my IDE I do not have this problem, only when running
 `./gradlew clean test` from the command line.

Ultimately it seems like a race condition, but I don't see how I can log before and after the closure execution, and not see logging that should occur inside of the closure.

---

As an update, I added code to log out the closure object at runtime and I'm seeing the following output (the code has been changed slightly in debugging, but the problem persists):

```
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Calling: StreamUtil$2@1edef6f9
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Calling:JMSProducerTest$_verifyJMSProducer_closure1@fa11e9d
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Called
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Finally
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Called
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Finally
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Calling: StreamUtil$2@1edef6f9
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Calling: JMSProducerTest$_verifyJMSProducer_closure1@fa11e9d
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Called
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Finally
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Called
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Finally
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Calling: JMSProducerTest$_verifyJMSProducer_closure1@fa11e9d
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Called
2016-01-12 14:56:04 INFO  JMSProducer - Finally
```

It looks like callback isn't the same thing consistently.  And only when I get StreamUtil$2@1edef6f9 is the callback executing.

Comment: Have you tried something other than using the logger to confirm the closure is running? Such as println. It could be an issue with logging rather than running the closure.

Comment: Can you debug the code? It would be really interesting to see how the `final closure` behaves inside the anonymous class implementing the `MessageListener ` interface.

Comment: The code is actually incrementing an atomic integer (and printing), and neither occur.  I originally thought it might be IO buffering as well.

Additionally, I haven't found a good way to debug outside of my IDE (where the problem doesn't occur).  I'm about to just look at the Java bytecode and see if something shows up.  I'm starting to think I've hit an edge case in Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so apparently there was a race condition in JMS, and a previous test was was somehow able to override the message listener (but only for a portion of the iterations). Not entirely certain how that occurred, but is something to do with asynchronous tests and JUnit.